# torchmetric calculate accuracy with threshold

Tags: pytorch

How does [`torchmetrics.Accuracy`](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/modules.html#id3) threshold keyword work? I have the following setup:

```py
import torch, torchmetrics

preds = torch.tensor([[0.3600, 0.3200, 0.3200]])
target = torch.tensor([0])
torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(preds, target, threshold=0.5, num_classes=3)
```

output:

```
tensor(1.)
```

None of the values in `preds` have a probability higher than `0.5`, why is it giving 100% accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`threshold=0.5` sets each probability under `0.5` to `0`. It is used only in case you are dealing with binary (which is not your case, since `num_classes=3`) or multilabel classification (which seems not the case because `multiclass` is not set). Therefore `threshold` is not actually involved.

In your case, `preds` represents a prediction related to one observation. Its largest probability (`0.36`) is set at position `0`, thus argmax(preds) and target are equal to `0`, therefore accuracy is set to 1, because the prediction of the (only) observation is correct.

Comment: Thanks, although I am not sure what this means. The same happens if preds equals `[[0.36, 0.32, 0.32], [0.36, 0.32, 0.32]]` and target equals `[0,0]`. `preds` is the softmax output and each element in target is a label from the set `{0, 1, 2}`. The accuracy should be 0 because none of the softmax outputs are higher than the threshold.

Comment: Maybe the labels need to start at 1? Giving the set `{1, 2, 3}` instead.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Actually, my previous explanation is wrong: The `threshold` parameter is actually not involved. The largest probability (`0.36`) is set at position `0`, thus argmax(preds) and target are equal to `0`, therefore accuracy is set to `1`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok, so `threshold` does nothing for multiclass classification problems?

Comment: It may be related. In the `accuracy` docs they actually speak of multilabel, which is sometimes a different concept than multiclass.  The point is that you shouldn't be concerned since you're just performing a simple non-binary classification.

Comment: I want to use a threshold, but I guess I need to calculate the metrics myself for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multilabel target shape with `subset_accuracy=True` as explained [here](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/modules.html#input-types)

```
import torch, torchmetrics

target = torch.tensor([0,1,2])
target = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target)
preds = torch.tensor([[0.3600, 0.3200, 0.3200],
                      [0.300,  0.4000, 0.3000],
                      [0.3000, 0.2000, 0.5000]])

torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(preds, target, subset_accuracy=True, threshold=0.6)
```

Output:

```
tensor(0.)
```

Decreasing threshold:

```
torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(preds, target, subset_accuracy=True, threshold=0.5)
```

Output:

```
tensor(0.333)
```

Decreasing threshold to 0.35:

```
torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(preds, target, subset_accuracy=True, threshold=0.35)
```

Output:

```
tensor(1.)
```

unfortunately this does not work for if any other probability is higher then the threshold, because it will think you are predicting multiple labels. For instance threshold 0.0 will give:

```
torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(preds, target, subset_accuracy=True, threshold=0.0)
```

Output:

```
tensor(0.)
```